# Soap errors when I update and InfoPath form to Sharepoint 2013

Tags: infopath, soap

Since we migrated to SharePoint 2013 from SharePoint 2010, every time we need to update an InfoPath Form we get the below error message.  Can anyone help with this.

The SOAP response indicates that an error occurred on the server:

> Exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
>   Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.